# Python create list from list of dictionaries for each dictionary that has a specific key

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I have a list of dictionaries that do not necessarily have the same keys.  I am trying to make a new list of the values contained in each dictionary that has a specific key.

E.g.

```
dict1 = {'key1': 1, 'key2': 2, 'key4': 4}
dict2 = {'key2': 2, 'key3': 3}
dict3 = {'key1': 1, 'key2': 2, 'key3': 3}

dict_list = [dict1, dict2, dict3]
```

Now I'm trying to create a list from dict_list as follows:

```
key2vals = [dict['key2'] for dict in dict_list]
print(key2vals)
   [2, 2, 2]
```

That works well, since 'key2' is contained in every dictionary in the list.  However, when I try a key that does not appear in every dictionary, I get a fault.  E.g. 'key1':

```
>>> key1vals = [dict['key1'] for dict in dict_list]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <listcomp>
KeyError: 'key1'
```

Is there a short and straightforward way that I can do something like the following, which does not work?

```
# This does not work
key1vals = [dict['key1'] if 'key1' in dict for dict in dict_list]
```

What is the most Pythonic way to accomplish this?

**ANSWER:**
The order of the for and if statements should have been reversed:

```
key1vals = [dict['key1'] for dict in dict_list if 'key1' in dict ]
```

Also, with AbrahamB and DJV's suggestions, I was able to add a default value to those dictionaries without the search key:

```
[dict.get('key1', 0) for dict in dict_list]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dict1 = {'key1': 1, 'key2': 2, 'key4': 4}
dict2 = {'key2': 2, 'key3': 3}
dict3 = {'key1': 1, 'key2': 2, 'key3': 3}

dict_list = [dict1, dict2, dict3]

keys = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3', 'key4', 'key5']
for key in keys:
    values = [d[key] for d in dict_list if key in d]
    print(values)
```

```
[1, 1]
[2, 2, 2]
[3, 3]
[4]
[]
```

But the same item lookup is done twice here: `key in d` and `d[key]`. You can avoid it:

```
    values = list(filter(None, (d.get(key) for d in dict_list)))
```

or

```
    values = [i for i in (d.get(key) for d in dict_list) if i is not None]
```

---

*Added*:
As you mentioned in comments, you actually need `0` if key is not in dict. Just use `get` method with default value:

```
    values = [d.get(key, 0) for d in dict_list]
```

```
[1, 0, 1]
[2, 2, 2]
[0, 3, 3]
[4, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely. The dict has a "get" method, which you can use.

For example

```
a = {}
a.get('this-does-not-exist')
```

That will return a None type.

Now you can get fancier, such as returning a default value if nothing is found:

```
a = {}
a.get('this-does-not-exist', [])
```

which will return an empty list [].

Comment: Can you use the a.get('key', 'defaultValue') format in the original example problem?  I'm not quite following how to use it in the bigger picture.

Comment: DJV just provided the answer in another comment:  [d.get('key1', 0) for d in dict_list]

Answer (score 1):

You were pretty close:

```
key1vals = [d['key1'] for d in dict_list if 'key1' in d]
```

To get all keys' values:

```
all_keys = {key for d in dict_list for key in d}

result_dict = {}
for key in all_keys:
    result_dict[key] = [d[key] for d in dict_list if key in d]

print(result_dict)
```

Which prints:

```
{'key1': [1, 1], 'key4': [4], 'key3': [3, 3], 'key2': [2, 2, 2]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions!  I found another solution which simply reversed the "for" and "if" statements in my previous attempt:

```
>>> key1vals = [dict['key1'] for dict in dict_list if 'key1' in dict]
>>> key1vals
[1, 1]
>>>
```

Would the filter or "get" methods be preferred to this?

Comment: I would suggest using the get since it is cleaner. You're already calling the key in dict['key1'], so this would be shorter as just dict.get('key1')

Comment: Either way. Yeah, it's shorter, but I think the `if 'key1' in d` language may be a bit more Pythonic and easier to read. That approach literally checks whether the dictionary even has a key `'key1'`. You can't go wrong either way.

Comment: Can I add an "else" statement, such as >>>key1vals = [dict['key1'] for dict in dict_list if 'key1' in dict else 0].  Then I would want key1vals to contain [1, 0, 1].

Comment: `[d.get('key1', 0) for d in dict_list]`